# Signika Negative Bold font doesnt work on my html site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Signika Negative Bold font doesnt work on my html site,
If I try some other fonts it works but with  `font-family: 'Signika Negative Bold';`

it doesnt work

html:

```
<div id="green">hewhehhwhehwe </div>
```

css:

```
#green {
font-family: 'Signika Negative Bold';
}
```

[this is what I have right now](https://jsfiddle.net/zaons289/1/)

Comment: how do you import it ? Where you use it ? Put more details if you want an answer !

Comment: Does the font have 'Bold" in its name? Have you tried 'Signika Negative' for a name and a bold font-weight?

Comment: @tomdebom If that is what you have, the answer surely must be that you don't have that font installed on your computer.

Comment: Since when do you need to instal fonts? @MrLister and without bold it also doesnt work

Comment: *Since when do you need to instal fonts?* Since **always**...in some cases your software might have them sntalled by default but it won't have **every** font by default...nor will your user's device.

Comment: @Paulie_D how do i do that? and is it a code so everyone who visiteds the page gets it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947766/how-to-install-a-font-in-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961721/how-do-i-install-a-custom-font-on-an-html-site

Answer (score -1):

Please Specify  font name and specify the URL, like shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    @font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(signika-v8-latin-regular.woff);
}


div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The @font-face Rule</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you do this in my case with the font i want?

Comment: change and add your font in 
src: url("your url");

Comment: and how do i know the url of my font? is that the google font link? or what?

Comment: You should download and keep the font file and add the url!